# How do we test LayoutClickListener and LayoutClickEvent in Junit4

Tags: java, junit4, vaadin7

I have been trying for a while to reach this methods from my test.class

**I am using Vaadin UI.**

The part that i am trying to reach is :

```
void initComponents() {
    setSizeFull();
    setMargin(true);
    setImmediate(true);

    loginHeadingView();
    getVLayout1().addLayoutClickListener(new LayoutClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void layoutClick(LayoutClickEvent event) {
            setLangView(0);
            removeHeadingView();
            removeComponent(log);
            setLangHead(0);
            initComponents();
            initValues();
        }
    });

    getVLayout2().addLayoutClickListener(new LayoutClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void layoutClick(LayoutClickEvent event) {
            setLangView(1);
            removeHeadingView();
            removeComponent(log);
            setLangHead(1);
            initComponents();
            initValues();
        }
    });
```

I cant reach the part of @Override method to test the values inside,

My aproach is :

```
LayoutClickListener testListener = Mockito.mock(LayoutClickListener.class);
  testLoginView.getVLayout1().addLayoutClickListener(testListener);
LayoutClickEvent testEvent = Mockito.mock(LayoutClickEvent.class);
  testListener.layoutClick(testEvent);
```

This makes sense to me , bu it is not working,Is it right the way of i am using Mock ? or else how do we do it ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a `spy` (also called partial mock). Mocking "fakes" all methods except instructed otherwise. Spying uses all original methods except instructed otherwise.

```
LayoutClickListener testListener = Mockito.spy(LayoutClickListener.class);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for you suggestion but this did not help me to fix the issue, maybe you can explain me more detailed or just try with some examples, because i did and it does not work